# Access SkyDrive using PHP and OAuth

Tags: php, api, oauth, onedrive

I would like to access skyDrive using PHP.
I want to retreive list of files and folders, download, upload and delete files.

I've got a microsoft dev clientID and clientSecret.

Can anybody get me started with connecting to skyDrive with OAuth and making use of the API?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually quite a broad question. Here's hopefully something that will get you started.

1. Have a look at [SkyDrives REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx).
2. You could use [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to perform the GET's and POST's.
3. Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to create a map of the received data.
4. For any data you send, create [maps](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP and convert them to JSON using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

---

## Try the API

[Here is an interactive API you can try out live to see the responses.](https://apigee.com/OneDrive/embed/console/OneDrive)

---

## Making requests

**[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10534144/1210983)** *(taken from other SO Answer)*:

```
$url = 'POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('access_token' => TOKEN, 'name' => 'file', 'filename' => "@HelloWorld.txt"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Request types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#http_verbs

I also recommend you have a look at [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to better understand how to do the different types of requests you'll be needing, using cURL. [*(Also this answer on SO has some good explanation on POST vs GET using cURL.)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1225518/1210983)

---

## [File object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#file)

- **DELETE FILES:**

  > To delete a file, make a DELETE request to /FILE_ID.
- **UPLOAD FILES:**

  > To create a new File resource, you can either make a POST request to /FOLDER_ID/files, a POST request to the /UPLOAD_LOCATION for the target folder, or a PUT request to /FOLDER_ID/files/.
- **DOWNLOAD FILES:**

  > To get properties for a File resource, make a GET request to /FILE_ID (the target file ID).

  - The File resource will contain the URL from which to download the file from SkyDrive in the **source** field.

---

## [Folder object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#folder)

- **RETRIEVE LIST OF FILES:**

  > To get the root Folder resource by using the Live Connect REST API, make a GET request to either /me/skydrive or /USER_ID/skydrive.
  >
  > To get a subfolder resource, make a GET request to /FOLDER_ID.
- **CREATE FOLDERS:**

  > To create a new Folder resource, make a POST request to /FOLDER_ID. Pass the name and description attributes in the request body
- **DELETE FOLDERS:**

  > To delete a folder, make a DELETE request to /FOLDER_ID.

---

## [OAuth 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx)

My experience with OAuth is unfortunately limited. I can only provide some relevant links  and advice which I hope will help.

[Review the Protocol Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx) and consider if you want to implement something yourself, or use a library. Quick Google search gives me:

- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2
- http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php

Some other potentially useful links and guides:

- See PHP section of http://oauth.net/code/