# Skydrive: Listing root files and folders in PHP

Tags: php, curl, onedrive

We would like to integrate Skydrive in our website, like we're currently doing with Google Drive but I'm lost in how to retrieve the root folders and files.

I've read these posts and docs:

- [Access SkyDrive using PHP and OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004750/access-skydrive-using-php-and-oauth)
- [Convert to PHP REST CURL POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534009/convert-to-php-rest-curl-post)
- Skydrive API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/
- Curl doc on http://php.net - even if I'm still confused about that

And yet, I can't seem to get what I wanted.

I've already the access_token and it's correctly assigned, the scopes are also correct (I'm using wl.contacts_skydrive), so, **I'm putting here part of the code I've so far so you can tell me what I'm missing, what I should add or if I'm taking a wrong turn.**

```
//$token is correctly assigned
$url = 'GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token='.$token;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Thanks you for your time taken to help me.

Comment: what is `$result` returning true or false?

Comment: Nothing appeared in $result, neither with echo or print-r. As I'm not currently at work, I'll see if i can be more precise tomorrow :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to return the transfer as a string.
Otherwise you will get true or false. Assuming you were getting true from `curl_exec`

Try adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing returned. I'm connected to the website with Elgg_Social_Login 1.7, with the OAuth2 protocol and with the rights scopes, so I retrieve their access token. Do I need the refresh token too? Or am not connected in Skydrive?

Comment: What do you exactly get from `curl_exec` I don't think you are connected with that token.
Check this http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-live-sdk
Also this might help
http://cgeers.com/2012/05/01/skydrive-listing-folders-and-files/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've read your sources - I'll come back to Skydrive after my vacations.